# What's the current consensus on which CUs to install?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, cumulative-update

Is there any "established" consensus on which Cumulative Updates are in general appropriate to install for a new SP 2013 installation?  I understand that the March 2013 Public Update is generally considered a Requirement, but - is there anything more recent that I generally "should" install, that isn't just to fix a specific problem?

Answer (score 1):

[December 2013](http://blogs.technet.com/b/stefan_gossner/archive/2013/12/20/december-2013-cu-for-sharepoint-2013-has-been-released.aspx) and [October 2013](http://blogs.technet.com/b/stefan_gossner/archive/2013/10/26/october-2013-cu-for-sharepoint-2013-has-been-released.aspx) had some issues. Although things are quite stable with [August 2013 CU](http://blogs.technet.com/b/stefan_gossner/archive/2013/08/14/august-2013-cu-for-sharepoint-2013-has-been-released.aspx).

You should only perform CU installation if you're having issues which needs to be fixed or you're way behind the patch levels. Remember, no CU provides warranties to your SharePoint farms.

Comment: Show me any MS product that provides a warranty. :)

Comment: We can definitely ask Google about it ;) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YuOBzWF0Aws

Answer (score 0):

Definitely install the March 2013 Public Update.

Otherwise, check Todd Klindt's SharePoint 2013 Build Numbers list for details about the other CUs. http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=346

In my view, CUs need not be applied unless they address a problem that you're experiencing in your farm.

Of course, SP1 is due to be released very soon (within a month or so?). Maybe just wait for that?